# Unable to save data from xml format in SQL table

Tags: sql-server, xml, stored-procedures

```
SELECT * 
FROM @myHierarchy 
FOR XML AUTO
```

Data is

```
<_x0040_myHierarchy element_id="1" parent_ID="1" NAME="itemCode" StringValue="Simmi" ValueType="string" />
```

I'm unable to load data in this query

```
SELECT @xml = dbo.ToXML(@myHierarchy);

SELECT 
    a.b.value('@ItemCode', 'varchar(20)') AS ItemCode 
FROM
    @xml.nodes('/root/_x0040_myHierarchy') a(b)
```

In this query, `itemcode` is blank. How can I load data using this query?

Comment: There is no attribute `ItemCode` in your sample XML ..... what are you trying to do? Which attribute do you want to get the value from??

Comment: i wanna retrieve stringvalue based upon name

Answer (score 1):

Your sample XML does *not* contain any attribute `ItemCode` - it has these attributes:

- `element_id`
- `parent_ID`
- `NAME`
- `StringValue`
- `ValueType`

So which value do you **really** want to read out from the XML element?

**Update:** to retrieve the `StringValue` attribute, use this code:

```
SELECT
    XC.value('@StringValue', 'varchar(50)')
FROM
    @xml.nodes('/_x0040_myHierarchy') AS XT(XC)
```

If your XML contains a `<root> ..... </root>` root element, and multiple `<_x0040_myHierarchy>` elements inside, and you want to extract the one with `@Name = 'itemCode'` - then you need to use this `SELECT`:

```
SELECT
    XC.value('@StringValue', 'varchar(50)')
FROM
    @xml.nodes('/root/_x0040_myHierarchy') AS XT(XC)
WHERE
    XC.value('@NAME', 'varchar(50)') = 'itemCode'
```

Comment: i wanna retrieve stringvalue based upon name